# How to add icons to drawer items using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

None of the other questions/answers related to adding icons to drawer items have worked.

Goal: use an image component as the drawer item's icon

Problem: using answers supplied to other questions doesn't work. I get `Reference Error: React is not Defined. The error is located at DrawerNavigatorItems at line {drawerIcon}`

DrawerNavigator route config code:

```
const drawerRouteConfig = {
    Inbox: {
        screen: InboxStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerIcon: () => (
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/img/white-inbox.png')}
                    style={{ height: width * 0.05, width: width * 0.05 }}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                />
            )
        }
    },
    Discover: DiscoverStack,
    Account: AccountStack,

};
```

How do I properly implement drawerItem icons?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I hadn't imported React.
fix: `import React from 'react'`